# How to remove these characters when tabbing on VIM

Tags: vimrc, macvim

I'm having this characters '>' when I'm tabbing using VIM. how can I remove this when tabbing? It's very annoying

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `list` is disabled by default and the default value of `listchars` doesn't contain `▶︎`. This means that **you** enabled `list` and **you** defined `listchars`. So… why ask? Just revert **your** own settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the `listchars` option. The idea is that you can display certain whitespace characters (tab, space, newline, etc.) as a different character so you can see them better. I'm guessing if you type:

```
:set listchars?
```

you will see something like

```
listchars=tab:(that arrow)
```

as well as some other settings. To disable this, you can change what tabs are displayed as, for example:

```
:set listchars+=tab:\ \
```

(note the trailing space)

or you may simply turn this off entirely by running

```
:set nolist
```

---

Recommended reading: `:h 'list'` and `:h listchars`